# xml load after exporting excel file failed

Tags: c#

I have a c# application with the following features:

- read a password from a config file.
- export an Excel file.

when I read the password at fist: it's ok. but once I export the Excel file, I can't no more read the password from config file. the following instruction fail.

```
xmlDoc.Load("Cfg.xml");
```

this issue appear only on Windows XP. on windows 7 it's ok.

the code for reading password from config file:

```
private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Check password
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load("Cfg.xml");
                XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Config/ManagerPW");

                if (node != null)
                {
                    string MangerPW = node.Attributes[0].Value;

                    PCCrypto PWCrypto = new PCCrypto();
                    if (PWCrypto.verifyMd5(this.Password.Text, MangerPW) == true)
                    {
                        isCorrectPassWord = true;
                        this.Dispose();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password!", "PW Authentication", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                           MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        this.Password.Text = "";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You tried to perform an unauthorized operation!", "PW Authentication", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                               MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    this.Password.Text = "";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in loading configuration file", "Configuration Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                               MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                this.Dispose(); 
            }

        }
```

the code of exporting Excel file

```
public bool exportToExcel(string path)
{
    bool bRet = true;
    int columnsNum = resultList.Columns.Count - 1;
    int rowsNum = resultList.Items.Count;
    object[,] array = new object[rowsNum + 1, columnsNum];

    //Change Current System Time to US
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    Excel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    Excel.Sheets xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkSheets[1];

    //disable alerts
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

    //Add Header to array            
    for (int i = 0; i < columnsNum; i++)
    {
        array[0, i] = resultList.Columns[i + 1].Text;
    }

    //Add Listview data to array
    for (int r = 0; r < rowsNum; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columnsNum; c++)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                array[r + 1, c] = resultList.Items[r].SubItems[c+1].Text;
            }));
        }
    }

    //Save array data into excel
    Excel.Range c1 = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
    Excel.Range c2 = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowsNum + 1, columnsNum];
    Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(c1, c2);
    xlRange.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;       
    xlRange.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";
    xlRange.Value2 = array;
    xlRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

    //Add Header color
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "I1").Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Aquamarine);

    //Save Excel file
    try
    {
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    }
    catch
    {
        bRet = false;
    }

    xlWorkBooks.Close();
    xlApp.Application.Quit();
    xlApp.Quit();
    releaseObject(c1);
    releaseObject(c2);
    releaseObject(xlRange);
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheets);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBooks);
    releaseObject(xlApp);

    return bRet;
}
```

Comment: Try specifying the full path in `xmlDoc.Load("Cfg.xml");` e.g. `xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\myfolder\Cfg.xml");` It might be that the current folder is being changed when you export the excel.

Comment: `I can't no more read the password from config file. the following instruction fail.` What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Can you tell us specifically what error your getting?  and please @germi don't use code formatting for quoting

Comment: thanks to @Ulric it solves the problem

Comment: @Med Besbes - I've posted it as an answer. I probably should have done that in the first place. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the full path in

```
xmlDoc.Load("Cfg.xml");
```

e.g.

```
xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\myfolder\Cfg.xml");
```

The current folder is being changed when you export the excel.